# Error 404 (GET) request error on Flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am new to Python and using Flask to deploy my app of a file uploader that does text extraction and returns the image with its pattern along with the image. The image is uploading properly in the **uploads** folder but when I want to display it (return function), the image appears broken due to which I am getting a 404 file not found error.

My folder path is as follows

```
.(main)
├── app
│   ├── static (folder)
│   └── templates (folder)
│   └── uploads //save all the uploaded images in this (folder)
|   └── upload.py  (file) <-- this file contains the code below
|   └── init.py    (file)
|   └── views.py   (file)
|
├── _tests
│   ├── footer.html
│   └── header.html
```

As per the relative path it is /app/static/uploads/

> But I get the **error "GET /app/uploads/34.png HTTP/1.1" 404** -
>
> I tried with ..app/uploads/ & ../../uploads/ but it still doesn't
> work, what changes can I make to solve this issue?

Also, the below function with upload_image is too long. How can I
reduce or split the function?

**Code: upload.py **

```
UPLOAD_INPUT_IMAGES_FOLDER = '/static/uploads/'

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # checks whether or not the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

    file = request.files['file']

    # if user does not select file, browser also
    # submit a empty part without filename
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No file selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)

    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd() +
                  UPLOAD_INPUT_IMAGES_FOLDER, filename))
        flash('File successfully uploaded')

    # calls the ocr_processing function to perform text extraction
        
        # extract the text and display it
        return render_template('upload.html',
                               msg='Processed successfully!',
                               img_src=UPLOAD_INPUT_IMAGES_FOLDER + file.filename)

    else:
        flash('Allowed image types are abc, abc, abc')
        return redirect(request.url)
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be a location error. Can you let me the error log also? Turn FLASK_DEBUG=1.

By the time, try this, keep your uploads folder inside static and try this.

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/logo_full.png')}}" alt="Theme-Logo"/>
```

Replace with your filename and attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The code provided by you needs to be added within the HTML layout. However this is not the case. The user uploads a random image which is getting stored in UPLOAD_INPUT_IMAGES_FOLDER = '/static/uploads/'

Though the image is getting stored properly in the above path '/static/uploads/', it appears broken when I try to display it back (def upload_image():)

Comment: Here is the flow:
1. User uploads image. The app checks for extension, whether the image is processed successfully or not, then extracts text using ocr 
2.  OCR works well, the image is stored within the path mentioned above.
3. Now the user gets the same image displayed back into the frontend, which is giving 404 error

Comment: Got it. Can you edit the question with the file where you are creating the app(app.py or similar)?

Comment: I've updated both the code with path and file structure :)